# Some code not executing when program is reset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a match color game. After the guesses are completed the initialize function is called, which resets the program. After the first set of guesses, when the initialize function is called again, code below the initialize function (two setTimeouts), that asks the user where a color is does not fire again. Thanks for the help.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>HTML 5 Boilerplate</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body style="pointer-events: none">
      <div class="question">
          <div class="questionbox">
              <p>Where is:</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="container-box">
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div> 
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
            <div class="colorbox"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="score-container">
        <div class="score">Score: <span id="score">0</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
    <button type="button" id="btn">Restart</button>

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.question {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.questionbox {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 33px;
}


.container-box {
    width: 600px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 400px;
}

.colorbox {
    display: flex;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    
}

.hide {
    background-color: grey !important;
}

.open {
   
    border: 40px white;
    cursor: default;
  }
  .button {
      width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
  }
  #btn {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50px;
      justify-content: center;
      
      text-align: center;

  }
  .score-container {
      display: flex;
      position: absolute;
      width: 100vw;
      justify-content: center;
      bottom: 100px;
  }

  .border {
      border: 8px solid #66ff00 !important;
  }
  .border-red {
    border: 8px solid #EE4B2B !important;
}
```

javascript

```
let colors = ["red", "yellow", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple"],
    $fullbox = $('.container'),
    $popup = $('.question'),
    gamecolor = [],
    $restart = $('#btn'),
    clicks = 0,
    guessColor = [],
    score = 0,
    guess;

window.onload = initialize();
// initialize board
function initialize () {
    clicks = 0;
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('border');
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('border-red');
    $('.colorbox').each(function () {
    $('body').css("pointer-events", "none");
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('hide');
     $(this).css("border", "2px solid black");
     let randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     $(this).css("background-color", `${randColor}`);
     setTimeout(hide, 3000);  
    })
}


function hide() {
    $('.colorbox').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hide');
    $('body').css("pointer-events", "auto");
    $('.colorbox').css("pointer-events", "auto");
    })
}
//restart
$('#btn').on('click', () => {
    initialize();
})

setTimeout(() => {
    $popup.css('display', 'flex');
    guessColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    $('.questionbox').find('p').after(`<span>&nbsp; ${guessColor}?</span>`);
}, 2500)

setTimeout(() => {
    $popup.css('display', 'none');
    $('body').css("pointer-events", "auto");
}, 6000)



$('.container').on('click', '.colorbox', function () {
    console.log($(this));
    $(this).css("pointer-events", "none");
    clicks++;
    guess = $(this)[0].style.backgroundColor;
    console.log(guess);
    $(this).removeClass('hide');
    console.log(guessColor);
    console.log(guess);
    if (guess === guessColor) {
        score;
        score++;
        $('#score').html(score);
        $(this).addClass('border');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('border-red');
        // $(this).css("border", "4px solid red");
    }
    if (clicks >= colors.length) {
        setTimeout(initialize, 800);
        $('body').css("pointer-events", "none");
    }
    console.log($(this));  
     
});
```

Comment: "After the first set of guesses, when the initialize function is called again, code below the initialize function (two setTimeouts), that asks the user where a color is does not fire again"  — Why should it? `initialize` does what `initialize` does. It doesn't do what `initialize` does and then also do everything written after `initialize` is finished.

Comment: Consider uploading the whole app to something like Stackblitz since you are sharing the whole code.

Comment: "Consider uploading the whole app to something like Stackblitz since you are sharing the whole code" — Don't do that. Provide a [mcve] instead. Emphasis on the minimal. There's a live demo button in the question editor.

Comment: @Quentin That'd be ideal but they shared the whole code anyway, seems like they weren't sure where the issue is so they couldn't isolate the frame of issue. It beats posting the whole thing in three blocks here?

Comment: @vfioox — There is a reason that the guidance for creating a [mcve] includes advice for narrowing where the problem is.

Comment: @vfloox I've never heard of stackblitz, is it commonplace?

Comment: @quentin the code below the two setTimeouts runs and they are not wrapped in a function, so wondering why the two setTimeouts won't run again as well

Comment: @Brian — Stuff happens when you tell it to happen, unless it is in a function in which case it happens then the function is called. Since the two setTimeouts aren't in a function, why should they run again? They already ran when you told them to run.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the timeouts aren't firing again, you need to put them within `initialize()`'s scope. Otherwise they are one-time only.

```
function initialize () {
    clicks = 0;
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('border');
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('border-red');
    $('.colorbox').each(function () {
    $('body').css("pointer-events", "none");
    $('.colorbox').removeClass('hide');
     $(this).css("border", "2px solid black");
     let randColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
     $(this).css("background-color", `${randColor}`);
     setTimeout(hide, 3000);  
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
        $popup.css('display', 'flex');
        guessColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
        $('.questionbox').find('p').after(`<span>&nbsp; ${guessColor}?</span>`);
    }, 2500)

    setTimeout(() => {
        $popup.css('display', 'none');
        $('body').css("pointer-events", "auto");
    }, 6000)
}
```